# Facebook like button does not appear in facebook iframe tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I encountered a problem on facebook where my like button does not appear sometimes and in iframe the chance that it won't appear is higher.

Well, I just added the script for fb like using xfbml declared xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb# part and etc. Then used this code for my like button:

```
<fb:like href="MY_URL_HERE_1" send="false" layout="button_count" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

and then I used the same code with different a URL for another like button 4 times. My other work works fine which has only one button, but on the page where I used 5 like buttons the problem then happens.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the like code you can find here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Or you can try this: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=354148#p354148

Comment: yes, I used that code and followed the steps and works fine on my other pages. But when I used multiple likes on the page the problem occurs. And by the way, I can't add those metas on the target page since the other page is not my work. Do you think it maybe the cause of the problem because the page having hard time in scraping it or something else?

Comment: Each 'like' has to represent one URL, so you should create pages for each post and then the user is able to like this page.

Comment: Yes i know about that thing. Well to explain more briefly let say I have one page with 5 like buttons each button like URL is different but the thing is I am not the one who created those pages. (e.g. google, facebook, yahoo) Then let say that those pages do not assign meta tags in their pages. Would it be the cause of the problem? And also one thing I observed. the button I placed when it appears there are around 300 likes already eventhough I just created it that time.